# How to fix this error in subquery so i can get distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

candidates table:

```
 id           name             age   
------       --------        --------- 
 25           Taylor          30
 113          Paul            21
 10           Laura            19
```

reports table:

```
 id           company        candidate_id      score
------       --------        -----------       ------ 
 1            Codility             10             20
 36              Soft             113             60
 137          Codility            10              30
 137          ITCompany           10              30
```

Query Should return:

```
 id           name             companies
------       --------        --------- 
 10           Laura            2 
 25           Taylor           0
 113           Paul            1
```

So far i'm able to retrieve the distinct candidates and companies from the reports table with this query `SELECT DISTINCT r.candidate_id, r.company FROM reports r` which gives me the candidates associated to distinct company:

```
candiate_id   company
------       --------        
 113           Soft           
 10           Codility         
 10          ITCompany
```

Now when i try to count the number of times the company appears for each candiate_id using the 'candidates table and use the above select query as a subquery I get an error saying. The query witht he subquery is:

```
SELECT r.candidate_id, COUNT(r.company) AS companies
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.candidate_id, r.company FROM reports r) as dr
GROUP BY r.candidate_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You _get an error saying_... what? Plus, you say you _try to count the number of times the company appears for each candiate_id_ but in the expected result looks like you want the number of _different companies_ for each candidate. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: group the result of a left join:

```
select c.id, c.name, 
       count(distinct r.company) as companies
from candidates c
  left join reports r on r.candidate_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name;  
order by c.id
```

Or join to the result of the aggregation:

```
select c.id, c.name, 
       coalesce(r.companies, 0) as companies
from candidates c
  left join (
     select candidate_id, count(distinct company) as companies
     from reports
     group by candidate_id
  ) r on r.candidate_id = c.id
order by c.id;
```

This works because the left join will yield `null` for candidates without reports and thus `count()` will count that with zero.

The second approach is sometimes faster than the first.

Comment: you sir are a legend! I had the thought process of using the result of aggregation hence the sub query but i think the left join makes more sense and is more simple! Thanks!